# jsonのtrueをTrueにしたい

Tags: python

```
json = {"Hi":true}
```

このHiのtrueをTrueにして論理演算できるようにしたいです。

Comment: 質問の意図が伝わらないです。1.挙げられているソースはPythonでは不適(質問文にある通りTrueが正しい) 2.jsonは普通はテキストの書式のことを言うのですが、もしかして変数名のことを言っている? 3.「trueをTrueに書きかえればよい」が普通に考える答えだけどそれじゃ駄目な理由、できない理由が書かれていない  4.「論理演算ができる」に意味は?

Answer (score 2):

[json.dumps](http://docs.python.jp/3/library/json.html) を使ってPythonのオブジェクトに変換できます。

```
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads('{"Hi":true}')
>>> d
{'Hi': True}
```